# Sort Parse Objects by Number

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, sorting, parse-platform

I have a few objects in a Parse database, a few are  as shown below.  I would like to sort these objects by highScore, which is stored as a number. 
(

```
"<Score: 0x7fee53740700, objectId: zMjL3eNWpI, localId: (null)> {\n    Score = \"High Score: 60\";\n    TeamName = \"Team0\";\n    highScore = 60;\n}",

"<Score: 0x7fee534b5080, objectId: nysaJjYsth, localId: (null)> {\n    Score = \"High Score: 86\";\n    TeamName = Team1;\n    highScore = 86;\n}",

"<Score: 0x7fee535f6ad0, objectId: 7Hj8RP4wYD, localId: (null)> {\n    Score = \"High Score: 23\";\n    TeamName = Team2;\n    highScore = 23;\n}"
```

)

I have the following code which I loop over the objects and pull out the Number highScore for each object, but I am not sure how to continue.  Is there a way I can return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending?  If anyone has any advice please let me know.  Thanks.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];//class name is Score
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {            
        for (int i = 0; i<=objects.count; i++){
        NSArray *array = [objects objectAtIndex:i];//Selects the first "object" from all the "objects"
        NSNumber *test= [objects objectAtIndex:i];
        array = [array valueForKey:@"highScore"];
        test = [test valueForKey:@"highScore"];               
         test1 = [test intValue];//test1 is the current database object highScore for the current object                        
        }     
    } else {
        // Log details of the failure
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse.com offers a great iOS SDK that already gives you out of the box what you are looking for. When you make a `PFQuery`, Parse gives you the option to order the results the way you would like. I believe you should try this:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];
[query orderByAscending:@"highScore"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {

        for (PFObject *object in objects) {
            NSLog(@"High Score is %d", [object["highScore"]intValue]);
        }

    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }

}];
```

Comment: Wow! this line worked: [query orderByAscending:@"highScore"];   When I tried to query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock I got the following error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'This query has an outstanding network connection. You have to wait until it's done.'  I removed that and the Leader board is sorted though.  Thanks Brandon!

Comment: You got it! Be sure to check out PFQueryTableViewController as well. Parse provides this class with their Parse.UI Framework that comes with their SDK. This is a custom GUI tool that assists you in querying data, persisting the data, and displaying your data in sorted UITableView. And if you think that's cool, check out PFQueryCollectionViewController!